# How to get the usage metrics data for the Web Application Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to execute the REST API to get the usage metrics data from Web Application deployed on Azure.

Hi,

I am trying to execute the REST API to get the usage metrics data from Web Application deployed on Azure.
 https://management.azure.com/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Web/sites//metrics?$filter=startTime%20eq%202016-04-12T06:05:42.907Z%20and%20endTime%20eq%202016-04-12T06:10:42.907Z&api-version=2014-04-01

But I am getting constantly 500 Internal Server Error.

Also, I tried to find out the given URL in Resource Explorer under the Mincrosoft.Web But in that I can see the metricsDefinitions but metrics is not available for this.

Can someone please let me know what how can I get the usage metrics data for the Web Application Services?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Can you please post your complete URL structure or request/response as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve resource metrics via the Azure Insights API.By using the Azure Insights API it is possible to programmatically retrieve the available default metric definitions (the type of metric such as CPU Time, Requests, etc.), granularity, and metric values.

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/{resource-provider-namespace}/{resource-type}/{resource-name}/metrics?api-version=2014-04-01&$filter={filter}`

It seems the REST API URI you are using is right, but before that the first step is to authenticate the Azure Insights API request. The easiest way to set up authentication is by creating an Azure AD service principal and retrieve the authentication token.

A very detailed walkthrough at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/02/23/retrieving-resource-metrics-via-the-azure-insights-api/.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I have set the authentication token, and by using that authentication token I got the MetricsDefinitions for the web application service, but I didn't get the Metrics data and got 500 Internal Server Error. Can you please let me know what needs to be done to get the metrics data for the Web Application Server?

Comment: Could you please provide more details, code or snapshot?

Comment: I am getting the access code from following code snippet:Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(
     tokenUrl, clientId, username, password, null); future.get().getAccessToken(); I am setting this to AUTHORIZATION_HEADER= "Bearer " + token.getAccessToken() in HTTPsURLConnection and executing this URL. Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: I reproduced you question which is raised by malformated filter. The `:` also needs to be escaped. Suggest you escape URI with tools rather than do it manually. Double check you URI especially the filter and go back to me.

Comment: I have tried to replace the : with "%3A" in the filter but same 500 Internal Server Error. https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/web_app_name/metrics?$filter=startTime%20eq%202016-04-13T04%3A45%3A20.0000837Z%20and%20endTime%20eq%202016-04-13T04%3A50%3A20.0000837Z&api-version=2014-04-01 Please let me know what else need to check over here?

Comment: In Resource Explorer "https://resources.azure.com" there is no REST API provided for the Web Application to get the metrics, even though there I can see the REST API to get the metricDefinitions. As for the SQL we have listed URL to get the metrics data I am not able to locate the URL to get the metrics for Web Application. Is Azure support this URL to get the metrics data as I can able to get the metrics definitions for web application?

Comment: You need to specify `timeGrain` which seems to be required by adding `timeGrain%20eq%20duration%27PT1M%27` in your filter. I tried and it worked.