# How to get cpu time for azure web apps using InsightsClient

Tags: c#, azure

I successfully get the metric name for azure web app but now I want to read that metric data. How it is possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36566155/382936 looks like it might help you. If not, please edit your question to explain what you've tried and the error messages you got.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

check above image you can see all metric in Metric per instance and in Metric per App